# Why is my Diadora Traccia's rear tire rub against the frame

Tags: mountain-bike, tire

Recently I took out my bike (Diadora Traccia) from storage (Basement) and started riding it in the new season. To my surprise, the rear tire began to rub on the frame whenever I pushed the right pedal. (Sorry couldn't get good camera angle for video to show, but the basic idea of the issue is when pressure is applied to the right pedal, the tire wobbles to the left and rubs against the frame making a car-exhaust type noise) Upon closer inspection (Taking the rear tire off), I discovered the following:

1. The right-side's bearing cover comes off whenever removing the tire ([Image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnXXk5PX0LXn3iLhspLsUwG5CZTm))
2. The right-side axel comes out ([Image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnXXk5PX0LXn3iAZJtOBMMDs9o2Z))
3. The left-side axel is wobbly ([Video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AnXXk5PX0LXn3iHiahvACMjo9DpG))

I've already tried to realign the wheel, leading to no avail.

Does anyone know how to even begin repairing this? Your help is greatly appreciated

TechMaster04

Comment: There’s only one axle, not a left and right. Your axle is snapped. You’ll have to replace it.

Comment: @Andrew That looks like an answer, to me.

Comment: I see. The tip of the axel didn't look snapped so I assumed this bike had one for each side (Which sounds stupid to me now). I'll look into axel replacements. Would you by any chance know how one would change an axel?

Comment: Park Tool has excellent tutorials. You may need a couple of special wrenches called cone wrenches, You may also need a free-hub or cassette removal tool. Bring both axle pieces to your local bike shop and they can supply a new axle along with loose bearings. On line videos are better than a written explanation

Comment: Take the wheel to the LBS and have them replace the axle. (And also clean the brake discs that have probably been contaminated with the grease from the axle bearings.)

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as a "left axle" and "right axle": your axle has snapped in two. Replacing it yourself will require specialized tools for the bearings and to remove and replace the rear sprockets: unless you think you'll use those tools again in the future, it's most likely cheaper to get a bike shop to do the repair for you. Or look to see if there's a bike co-op in your area.